# convexity of a piecewise function

Tags: convex-analysis

How can I show that the below function is convex in $x$ and convex in $e$?  $x_1 , x_2\geq 0$ and $e$ is a random variable which has a limited expectation.

\begin{equation}
Q(x,e)=\begin{cases}
1-x_1 & 0\leq e <x_1+x_2\\
e+1-2x_1-x_2 & x_1+x_2 \leq e <1+x_2\\
2(e-x_1-x_2) & 1+x_2\leq e
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: Adjective "random" in "$e$ is a random variable" can be omitted, i.e., the probabilistic context can be forgotten.

Comment: @LinAlg The book mentions that it is convex.

Comment: @Rose any comments on my answer?

Comment: @LinAlg so sorry for my delayed response. You are right.  I just have found out that there is an assumption that $0 \le x_1 \le 1$ and $0 \le x_2 \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is an error in the function definition. Take $x_1=e=2$ fixed, then the function simplifies to:
$$f(x) = Q((2,x),2) = \begin{cases}-1 & 0 \leq 2 < 2+x \\ -1-x & 2+x \leq 2 < 1+x \\ -2x & 1+x \leq 2 \end{cases}$$
The second case can never occur, and the other two cases can be simplified to:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}-1 & 0 < x \\ -2x & x \leq 1 \end{cases}$$
How do I evaluate this function at $x=0.5$?